# how to get URL with two parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i works in a MVC 4 project, and i have a small problem in my script, this is my script :

```
    function IsReportCheckpoint(cc,carNum) {
    var url = '/Home/IsReportAlertWebService/'+cc+',' + carNum;//here my problem
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: url,
        data: {},
        datatype: 'json',
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("input[name=Report]").on('click', function () {
        var carNumber = $(this).data('carnum'); 
        IsReportCheckpoint(c,carNumber);
});

});
```

my problem is the script consider the two parameters in the **URL** as one parameter, so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if using jquery POST, do:

```
var url = '/Home/IsReportAlertWebService';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { 'cc' : cc, 'car_num' : carNum },
        datatype: 'json',
       success: function( response ) {
           //response from server here
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

They way you are formatting it, you're not sending any parameters at all. A propertly formatted URL with query parameters look like this: `http://host/path?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value`. I don't know how your backend expects the url to be, or what the name of your parameters are, but I would suspect that it should be

```
var url = '/Home/IsReportAlertWebService/?cc=' + cc + '&carNum=' + carNum;
```

Or simply format a proper `data` object instead.

Answer (score 1):

Url parameters is probably what you are looking for and are created like this:

```
/path/to/my/webapp?cc=somevalue&carNum=453
```

The first Url parameter has a '?' before it and all the others are separated by '&'.

Answer (score 1):

check this : [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)
and then you can try :

```
var url = '/Home/IsReportAlertWebService/?cc="+cc+"&carNum="+carNum;
```